# How prove $\binom{n}{m}\le\left(\frac{en}{m}\right)^m$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

Show that
$$\binom{n}{m}\le\left(\dfrac{en}{m}\right)^m$$
where $0<m\le n,m,n\in N^{+}$

My idea: since
$$(\dfrac{n}{m}-\dfrac{m-1}{m})(\dfrac{n}{m}-\dfrac{m-2}{m})\cdots\dfrac{n}{m}\le\left(\dfrac{en}{m}\right)^m$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\ln{\left(\dfrac{n}{m}-\dfrac{m-i}{m}\right)}\le m\ln{\dfrac{en}{m}}$$

then I can't,Thank you

Comment: Is [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) allowed?

Comment: perhaps induction?

Comment: What is e? Integer? What bounds?

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528852/simple-upper-bound-for-binomnk/528885#528885

Answer (score 2):

First note that

$${n\choose m}=\frac1{m!}\prod_{k=n-m+1}^nk\le\frac1{m!}\prod_{k=n-m+1}^nn=\frac{n^m}{m!}.$$

Furthermore, the bound form of Stirling's approximation is

$$m!\ge\sqrt{2\pi m}\left(\frac me\right)^m\ge\left(\frac me\right)^m,$$

so

$${n\choose m}\le\frac{n^m}{m!}\le\left(\frac{en}m\right)^m.$$